# Binary operator overloading with class and constant in C++

Tags: c++, function, operator-overloading

I am trying to do operator overloading

My header is:

```
class Nyble

{
public:

Nyble();
Nyble(const Nyble& n);
Nyble& operator=(const Nyble& n);
~Nyble();
Nyble operator+(const char a);
Nyble operator-(const char a);
Nyble operator+(Nyble& n1);
Nyble operator+();
unsigned char getData();

private:
    // Do not change this data
unsigned char data;
```

}

Source:

```
#include "Nyble.h"

unsigned char Nyble::getData()
{
    return this->data;

}

Nyble Nyble::operator+(const char val)
{   
    return  Nyble(getData()+val);
}

Nyble Nyble::operator-(const char value)
{
    return Nyble(value + getData()) ;
}``
```

I am getting an error saying no suitable constructor exists to convert int to Nyble. If so, what constructor should I declare? Else what changes should I make to the overloading function?

Comment: The line ```return  Nyble(getData()+val);``` attempts to construct a Nyble using an int argument.  You have no constructor declared for Nyble that takes an int or compatible type as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a constructor for `Nyble(getData() + val);` and `Nyble(value + getData())` to work:

```
class Nyble {
public:
    explicit Nyble(char d);       // add this
    // ...
};

Nyble::Nyble(char d) : data(d) {} // and the implementation
```

---

Though, I recommend that you instead implement `operator+` and `operator-` as free functions and make `operator+=` and `operator-=` member functions.

It could look like this:

```cpp
class Nyble {
public:
    Nyble() = default;
    explicit Nyble(unsigned char d);
    
    // implement operator+= and operator-= as member functions
    Nyble& operator+=(const Nyble& n1);
    Nyble& operator-=(const Nyble& n1);

    unsigned char getData() const;
    unsigned char& getData();

private:
    unsigned char data = 0;
};

// operator+ and operator- as free functions:
Nyble operator+(Nyble lhs, const Nyble& rhs);
Nyble operator-(Nyble lhs, const Nyble& rhs);
```

```
Nyble::Nyble(unsigned char d) : data(d) {}

// the implementation of the member operator overloads:
Nyble& Nyble::operator+=(const Nyble& rhs) {
    data += rhs.data;
    return *this;
}
Nyble& Nyble::operator-=(const Nyble& rhs) {
    data -= rhs.data;
    return *this;
}

unsigned char Nyble::getData() const { return data; }
unsigned char& Nyble::getData() { return data; }

// now the free functions can use the member functions
// `operator+=` and `operator-=`:
Nyble operator+(Nyble lhs, const Nyble& rhs) {
    return lhs += rhs;
}

Nyble operator-(Nyble lhs, const Nyble& rhs) {
    return lhs += rhs;
}
```

Comment: thanks but why make two member functions and two free functions when member functions might be enough